# Issue with IfNull using a join | Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need some help. I've got three tables that I need information from. The most important parameter is the `DealID` from my table `Flostream.orders`. If this is null, I want it replaced with the `Mobileheads.survey.sales_rule` which is the same format.

I've constructed this:

```
SELECT
    filename,
    IFNULL(dealID,mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule) AS DealIDcombo,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(integer(weight)) AS TotalWeight,
    SUM(Productweight)/1000 AS SumWeight,
    Currency,
    Deliverybasecost,
    ROUND(SUM(Deliverybasecost),2) AS TotalDelCost,
    Productsku,
    Productname,
    Dealstartdate
FROM
    [flostream.orders] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN flostream.briisk 
        ON dealID = Uniquereference
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mobileheads.surveys
        ON mobileheads.surveys.order_number = ExternalReference
GROUP BY 
    filename,
    DealIDCombo,
    currency,
    Deliverybasecost,
    Productname,
    Productsku,
    dealstartdate
ORDER BY
    filename,
    Total desc;
```

My issue is with this:

```
LEFT outer JOIN flostream.briisk ON dealID = Uniquereference
```

Ideally I would like it to be:

```
LEFT outer JOIN flostream.briisk ON dealIDCombo = Uniquereference
```

but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the join can't access fields that are computed after the join.

See how `Ifnull` uses the joined table. You need to nest these tables.

First the join with `mobileheads.surveys` and then the next join.

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT
    filename,
    IFNULL(dealID,mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule) AS DealIDcombo,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(integer(weight)) AS TotalWeight,
    SUM(Productweight)/1000 AS SumWeight,
    Currency,
    Deliverybasecost,
    ROUND(SUM(Deliverybasecost),2) AS TotalDelCost,
    Productsku,
    Productname,
    Dealstartdate
  FROM
    [flostream.orders]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mobileheads.surveys
      ON mobileheads.surveys.order_number = ExternalReference) as first
LEFT OUTER JOIN flostream.briisk
    ON first.dealIDCombo = Uniquereference
GROUP BY 
  filename,
  DealIDCombo,
  currency,
  Deliverybasecost,
  Productname,
  Productsku,
  dealstartdate
ORDER BY
   filename,
   Total desc;
```

Excuse the mess, i don't know where these field belong to. Hopefully this helps. Ask me if you need more explanation!